# Cannot create index in JanusGraph

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph, scylla

I've installed JanusGraph 0.5.2 with ScyllaDB 4.2.1 and Elasticsearch 6.6.0 and I'm trying to create a fulltext index according to the docs as follows:

```
1. mgmt = graph.openManagement()
2. PropertyKey value = mgmt.makePropertyKey('value').dataType(String.class).make()
3. mgmt.buildIndex('verticesByValue', Vertex.class).addKey(value, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search")
4. mgmt.commit()
```

It throws this error after I enter the 3. step:

```
No signature of method: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem$IndexBuilder.addKey() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T$4, org.janusgraph.core.schema.Parameter) values: [value, mapping->TEXT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
PropertyKey value = mgmt.makePropertyKey('value').dataType(String.class).make()
```

Use This:

```
value = mgmt.makePropertyKey('value').dataType(String.class).make()
```

I was able to generate the issue when I used "**PropertyKey**" type to assign to value.